# Youtube Data API Like Insertion

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

Can Some one help me with the following code? I am not able to insert the like into the video.

```
    List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner",
                   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

            GoogleAccountCredential credential;


            credential =  GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), scopes);
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(DSCActivity.this);
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(sp.getString(Constants.ACCOUNT_KEY, null));
            credential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

            String appName = "xyz App"; // This is registered in the google developer console
             YouTube youtube =
                    new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
                            appName).build();


          YouTube.Videos.Rate obj = youtube.videos().rate(id,requiredAction);

 // Here id is video ID and requiredAction is like
```